# Changing Astropy WCS projection

Tags: python, astropy, fits, wcs

I use the below python script to read the world coordinate system (WCS) form a fits file and plot it.

```
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.wcs import WCS

hdu = fits.open('file.fits')
header = hdu[0].header
data = hdu[0].data
wcs = WCS(header, naxis=2)

plt.figure().add_subplot(1,1,1, projection=wcs)
plt.imshow(data)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

However, the above script projects the image in RA and DEC. I was wondering if there is a way to make it show the image in Azimuth and Elevation.

Thanks.

Comment: The azimuth and elevation will depend on your position on Earth and on the time it is, so converting from (right ascension, declination) to (azimuth, elevation) is actually non trivial. Do you have any other information you can use?